# use a perl script to make files same extension filename

Tags: python, perl, file, gaussian

I have a Python script that extracts a set of numbers from a chemistry program log file and sorts them in ascending order.

How can I use Perl to make the script read more than one file and make a `.dat` file for each `.log` file?

The script automatically makes a `.dat` file, but if I use it on more than one `.log` file, it overwrites each `.dat` file and makes just one `.dat` file.

This is what I'm typing at the prompt:

```
for i in `ls *log`; do perl thermo.pl $i; done
```

I'm guessing that something inside the script is telling it to only process one file at a time.

I did not write the script; it is from the [NIST site](https://www.nist.gov/).

Comment: Have you tried `perl thermo.pl *log`?

Comment: I know it all looks easy, but if you can't write software then you should be paying someone who can to fix your problem. You shouldn't hope for a free solution on Stack Overflow. How would you deal with a request for a free solution to a chemistry problem?

Comment: I have added to your question a hyperlink to "the NIST site", which is the only clue you gave, but we need to see the contents of `thermo.pl` before we can even begin to help you. If you show that code (or link to it properly) then maybe you will find someone willing to offer their services for free.

Comment: @AKHolland: From the OP's description it sounds like `thermo.pl` appends to a file with a hard-coded name. You have no reason to believe that it can accept multiple file names on the command line.

Comment: *"The script automatically makes a `.dat` file"* What is that file called?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Comment: @Borodin I agree, it's hard to make any conclusions based on the information provided, so I wouldn't post it as an answer. It seems like something that had a chance at resolving the issue, and would be easy to try.

Comment: @AKHolland: No one would try things at random if they could see the contents of `thermo.pl`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The link to the python script is here:
https://www.nist.gov/mml/csd/informatics_research/thermochemistry_script

I tried the method of Borodin and Kosh, but the script continues to make a single file called thermo.dat that overwrites each subsequent .dat file.

I'm sorry if I've violated protocol by asking for free assistance. I was hoping that my problem would need a simple solution. I was under the impression that this is a collegial group similar to the computational chemistry sites that I frequent. There, if I know the answer, I offer my solution for free.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not a Perl question.

Might you try something like this:

(change result_file.dat to the actual .dat filename which your perl script makes)

```
for i in `ls *log`; do perl thermo.pl $i && mv result_file.dat $i.dat; done
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm sorry that I did not include the code for thermo.pl. Here it is:

Comment: Heath Watts, did you changed <result_file.dat> in my example to <thermo.dat> before run it? It should be like this:
---    

`for i in \`ls *log\`; do perl thermo.pl $i && mv thermo.dat $i.dat; done`
 --- 

What result did you get?